# How to store multidimensional array values to MySQL database in java?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, jdbc, multidimensional-array

I would like to ask how to store multidimensional array to MySQL database. 
For example i have an array of (x, y)

```
array[][] = {
{3, 10},
{2, 11},
{4, 9},
}
```

i tried using preparedStatement setInt to store those values to mysql database but the output turned out like this:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

this is the code :

```
import java.sql.*; 
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class InsertDB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null; 
        Statement exe = null; 



    int[][] multiarray = { 
               {3, 10},
               {2, 11},
               {4, 9},
            };

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Connecting to the database");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/finalproject","root","");
            System.out.println("Database connected");
            exe = conn.createStatement();

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SIGNATURE (angle, distance) VALUES (?,?)");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               stmt.setInt(1, multiarray[i][0]);
               stmt.setInt(2, multiarray[i][1]);
               stmt.addBatch();
            }

            stmt.executeBatch();
            conn.commit();

            System.out.println("Data added !  ");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InsertDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InsertDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
            try{
                if (exe != null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch (SQLException se){

            }try{
                if(conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){

            }
    }
        System.out.println("Done !");
    }

}
```

can someone solve this problem,

thanks :)

Comment: `can someone solve this problem` Not unless you show the code that fails...

Comment: **Array Index Out Of Bounds:** ***3***

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3` -- the `3` is the index value that is out of bounds.  But without the source code nobody here can help you and the question will attract downvotes and be closed.

Comment: Please send the code... The code that is giving this error

Comment: And please share the relevant part of the stacktrace showing where in your code the exception is thrown, just in case the error is not obvious...

Comment: sorry, i forgot to share my code. I've added my code above

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array to a string and then you can save.

Answer (score 0):

The Stacktrace of the exception most likely points into the for loop and the exception imho explains the problem quite accurately:

Your array `multiarray` has 3x2 elements, i.e. `multiarray[0..2][0..1]`. In your for loop, you iterate `i` up to 10 and try to access `multiarray[3][0]` - as 3 is an invalid index, you get the appropriate exception, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Make sure you don't iterate further than the size of your array and your code works fine:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < multiarray.length; i++) {
    stmt.setInt(1, multiarray[i][0]);
    stmt.setInt(2, multiarray[i][1]);
    stmt.addBatch();
  }
```

BTW: Your question implies that you want to store a multidimensional array into a single database field. This might make sense in certain conditions but is a rare case and support for it poor or not standardized.

The code you're showing is not really storing a multidimensional array into the database - you're storing individual integers into a db table. The multidimensional array is just your representation in Java of the data in the database table.

You might want to clarify your question.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i tried to change the loop to multiarray.length but it didn't work, it gave the same exception as before. the array above is just an example. actually i'm making a shape detection in image processing. the output of the feature extraction is multidimensional array contains of {angle, distance} of image object. i want to insert those value to database so i can retrieve that to the other operations. do you have any solution ? thanks before :)